# What does it mean "can/cannot be willed away"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> The urge to return is too strong. It cannot be willed away.

I saw these lines while I was watching the TV series. I couldn't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: It would be useful to have more context and a source for this quote.  It most likely  means something can/cannot be made to disappear or vanish through mental activity (desire / faith / willpower).

Comment: "The urge to return is too strong.
It cannot be willed away." I saw these lines while I was watching the TV series

Comment: Right, as I thought then.  I'll answer.

Comment: to will something away. Look in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It means it (the urge to return) cannot be made to disappear or vanish by the force of  desire, thought, willpower, etc.  "Willing" something to happen (or not happen) is similar to "wishing" something to happen, or "urging" something to happen.